# C# Ensuring the existence of random number

Tags: c#, random

I am currently in the process of creating an educational game to help people learn maths but have stumble across an issue.

I am randomizing the text within some cubes that the player clicks on to test their knowledge of multiples, however the code i am using at the moment makes it so that occasionally there is no correct answer on the screen, is there a way i can remedy this?

Code:

**Buttons**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RNG : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GUIText thisAnswer;
    public RandomiseAll reRoll;
    int randomNumber = 0;
    int miniScore = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake ()
    {
            randomNumber = Random.Range (0, 36);

            thisAnswer.text = randomNumber.ToString ();
    }

    void OnMouseUpAsButton ()
    {

            if (randomNumber % 3 == 0) {
                    miniScore += 100;
                    reRoll.Randomise ();
                    Debug.Log (miniScore.ToString ());
            } else if (randomNumber % 3 != 0) {
                    reRoll.Randomise ();
                    Debug.Log (miniScore.ToString ());
            }
    }
```

}

**Global Re-Randomise**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RandomiseAll : MonoBehaviour {

public GUIText[] answer;

int randomNumber;
int[] test;
public void Randomise(){

    for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++) {
                    randomNumber = Random.Range (0, 36);
                    answer [i].text = randomNumber.ToString ();
            }

}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you get duplicate answers as well?

Comment: Unless you're doing a reverse quiz (Jeopardy), `thisAnswer.text = randomNumber.ToString();` is so deeply wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming GuiText[] answer is where you save all the possible options, a solution could be to loop over it after randomising to verify that at least one answer is correct.

This solution uses LINQ.

```
public void Randomise(){

    for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++) {
        randomNumber = Random.Range (0, 36);
        answer [i].text = randomNumber.ToString ();
    }

    if (!(Answer.Any(p => (Convert.ToInt32(p)) % 3 == 0)))
        Randomise();
}
```

Without LINQ:

```
public void Randomise(){

    for (int i = 0; i < answer.Length; i++) {
        randomNumber = Random.Range (0, 36);
        answer [i].text = randomNumber.ToString ();
    }

    bool anyExist = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < answer.Length; j++)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToInt32(answer[j].text) % 3 == 0)
        {
            anyExist = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!anyExist)
        Randomise();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just add the correct answer along with a bunch of other random wrong answers?

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to say, if you know there are 10 answers. Generate 9 wrong Answers along side the correct answer.

Comment: Is a question an answer? Looks more like a comment to me.